# matplotlib matrix visualisation: controling precision on float values

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, physics, data-science

I am using matplotlib for the first time to visualize the following matrix:

```
[[ 150.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.   ]
 [ 150.      69.388   35.36    18.211    7.851    0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.      -0.03    -0.047   -0.044   -0.027    0.   ]
 [ 150.      92.192   53.842   29.633   13.192    0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.      -0.075   -0.112   -0.104   -0.062    0.   ]
 [ 150.      95.538   58.184   33.287   15.285    0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.      -0.156   -0.221   -0.199   -0.116    0.   ]
 [ 150.      81.776   50.068   30.045   14.659    0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.      -0.331   -0.416   -0.357   -0.203    0.   ]
 [   0.      31.498   30.267   22.168   13.308    5.653    2.766    1.5      0.86     0.492    0.254    0.082   -0.058   -0.182   -0.298   -0.41    -0.515   -0.617   -0.751   -0.754   -0.609   -0.34     0.   ]
 [   0.      13.948   17.335   15.05    10.751    6.537    3.913    2.374    1.447    0.854    0.443    0.13    -0.132   -0.372   -0.602   -0.826   -1.034   -1.204   -1.301   -1.241   -0.985   -0.548    0.   ]
 [   0.       6.958   10.074    9.949    8.107    5.832    3.973    2.635    1.7      1.034    0.534    0.129   -0.229   -0.57    -0.913   -1.258   -1.59    -1.864   -2.007   -1.924   -1.543   -0.866    0.   ]
 [   0.       3.812    6.053    6.564    5.896    4.712    3.511    2.493    1.685    1.048    0.529    0.079   -0.342   -0.768   -1.22    -1.705   -2.203   -2.654   -2.941   -2.904   -2.395   -1.375    0.   ]
 [   0.       2.237    3.761    4.358    4.202    3.609    2.867    2.142    1.498    0.943    0.455    0.002   -0.452   -0.94    -1.495   -2.139   -2.864   -3.607   -4.2     -4.357   -3.76    -2.237    0.   ]
 [   0.       1.375    2.396    2.906    2.943    2.656    2.206    1.708    1.223    0.771    0.345   -0.076   -0.526   -1.045   -1.682   -2.491   -3.509   -4.71    -5.895   -6.563   -6.052   -3.812    0.   ]
 [   0.       0.867    1.543    1.925    2.009    1.865    1.592    1.261    0.915    0.573    0.232   -0.126   -0.531   -1.031   -1.698   -2.633   -3.971   -5.831   -8.105   -9.948  -10.073   -6.958    0.   ]
 [   0.       0.548    0.986    1.242    1.302    1.205    1.035    0.828    0.604    0.373    0.134   -0.128   -0.441   -0.852   -1.445   -2.372   -3.911   -6.536  -10.749  -15.049  -17.334  -13.947    0.   ]
 [   0.       0.34     0.609    0.755    0.751    0.618    0.516    0.411    0.299    0.183    0.059   -0.081   -0.253   -0.491   -0.859   -1.499   -2.766   -5.652  -13.307  -22.167  -30.267  -31.497    0.   ]
 [   0.       0.203    0.357    0.416    0.331    0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.     -14.659  -30.045  -50.068  -81.776 -150.   ]
 [   0.       0.116    0.2      0.221    0.157    0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.     -15.284  -33.286  -58.184  -95.538 -150.   ]
 [   0.       0.062    0.104    0.112    0.075    0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.     -13.192  -29.633  -53.842  -92.192 -150.   ]
 [   0.       0.027    0.044    0.047    0.03     0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.      -7.851  -18.211  -35.36   -69.388 -150.   ]
 [   0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.    -150.   ]]
```

The problem I have is that the default precision of the rendering doesn't show the difference between the values in the center, which are the most important for my application:
[image: matplotlib visualization]

since my values range from 150 to -150, matplotlib gives the same color to all the middle values, which are [-5,5]

I would like to manipulate the scaling to generate some kind of heat map showing the progression throughout the figure.

Pertinent python code:

```
    plt.matshow(mat, aspect='auto', cmap=plt.get_cmap('magma'))
    plt.show()
```

What would be the easiest way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can tweak with that:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
mat = [[ 150. ,  0.    ,   0.     ,  0.   , 0.   ,  0.   ,    0.     ,  0.     ,  0.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ,  0.  ,   0.  ,     0.    ,   0.   ,    0.    ,   0.     ,  0.   ,  0.     ,  0.     ,  0.      , 0.     ,  0.   ],
       [ 150. , 69.388 ,  35.36   , 18.211, 7.851,  0.   ,    0.     ,  0.     ,  0.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ,  0.  ,   0.  ,     0.    ,   0.    ,   0.   ,    0.     ,  0.   ,  -0.03  ,  -0.047 ,  -0.044  , -0.027 ,   0.   ],
       [ 150. , 92.192 ,  53.842  , 29.633,13.192,  0.   ,    0.     ,  0.     ,  0.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ,  0.  ,   0.  ,     0.    ,   0.    ,   0.   ,    0.     ,  0.   ,  -0.075 ,  -0.112 ,  -0.104  , -0.062 ,   0.   ],
       [ 150. , 95.538 ,  58.184  , 33.287,15.285,  0.   ,    0.     ,  0.     ,  0.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ,  0.  ,   0.  ,     0.    ,   0.    ,   0.   ,    0.     ,  0.   ,  -0.156 ,  -0.221 ,  -0.199  , -0.116 ,   0.   ],
       [ 150. , 81.776 ,  50.068  , 30.045,14.659,  0.   ,    0.     ,  0.     ,  0.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ,  0.  ,   0.  ,     0.    ,   0.    ,   0.   ,    0.     ,  0.   ,  -0.331 ,  -0.416 ,  -0.357  , -0.203 ,   0.   ],
       [   0. , 31.498 ,  30.267  , 22.168,13.308,  5.653,    2.766  ,  1.5    ,  0.86  ,   0.492  ,  0.254  , 0.082, -0.058,   -0.182  , -0.298 ,  -0.41 ,   -0.515  , -0.617,  -0.751 ,  -0.754 ,  -0.609  , -0.34  ,   0.   ],
       [   0. , 13.948 ,  17.335  , 15.05 ,10.751,  6.537,    3.913  ,  2.374  ,  1.447 ,   0.854  ,  0.443  , 0.13 , -0.132,   -0.372  , -0.602  , -0.826 ,  -1.034  , -1.204,  -1.301 ,  -1.241 ,  -0.985  , -0.548 ,   0.   ],
       [   0. ,  6.958 ,  10.074  ,  9.949, 8.107,  5.832,    3.973  ,  2.635  ,  1.7   ,   1.034  ,  0.534  , 0.129, -0.229,   -0.57   , -0.913  , -1.258 ,  -1.59   , -1.864,  -2.007 ,  -1.924 ,  -1.543  , -0.866 ,   0.   ],
       [   0. ,  3.812 ,   6.053  ,  6.564, 5.896,  4.712,    3.511  ,  2.493  ,  1.685 ,   1.048  ,  0.529  , 0.079, -0.342,   -0.768  , -1.22   , -1.705 ,  -2.203  , -2.654,  -2.941 ,  -2.904 ,  -2.395  , -1.375 ,   0.   ],
       [   0. ,  2.237 ,   3.761  ,  4.358, 4.202,  3.609,    2.867  ,  2.142  ,  1.498 ,   0.943  ,  0.455  , 0.002, -0.452,   -0.94   , -1.495  , -2.139 ,  -2.864  , -3.607,  -4.2   ,  -4.357 ,  -3.76   , -2.237 ,   0.   ],
       [   0. ,  1.375 ,   2.396  ,  2.906, 2.943,  2.656,    2.206  ,  1.708  ,  1.223 ,   0.771  ,  0.345  ,-0.076, -0.526,   -1.045  , -1.682  , -2.491 ,  -3.509  , -4.71 ,  -5.895 ,  -6.563 ,  -6.052  , -3.812 ,   0.   ],
       [   0. ,  0.867 ,   1.543  ,  1.925, 2.009,  1.865,    1.592  ,  1.261  ,  0.915 ,   0.573  ,  0.232  ,-0.126, -0.531,   -1.031  , -1.698  , -2.633 ,  -3.971  , -5.831,  -8.105 ,  -9.948 , -10.073  , -6.958 ,   0.   ],
       [   0. ,  0.548 ,   0.986  ,  1.242, 1.302,  1.205,    1.035  ,  0.828  ,  0.604 ,   0.373  ,  0.134  ,-0.128, -0.441,   -0.852  , -1.445  , -2.372 ,  -3.911  , -6.536, -10.749 , -15.049 , -17.334  ,-13.947 ,   0.   ],
       [   0. ,  0.34  ,   0.609  ,  0.755, 0.751,  0.618,    0.516  ,  0.411  ,  0.299 ,   0.183  ,  0.059  ,-0.081, -0.253,   -0.491  , -0.859  , -1.499 ,  -2.766  , -5.652, -13.307 , -22.167 , -30.267  ,-31.497 ,   0.   ],
       [   0. ,  0.203 ,   0.357  ,  0.416, 0.331,  0.   ,    0.     ,  0.     ,  0.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ,  0.  ,   0.  ,     0.    ,   0.     ,  0.    ,   0.     ,  0.   , -14.659 , -30.045 , -50.068  ,-81.776 ,-150.   ],
       [   0. ,  0.116 ,   0.2    ,  0.221, 0.157,  0.   ,    0.     ,  0.     ,  0.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ,  0.  ,   0.  ,     0.    ,   0.    ,   0.   ,    0.     ,  0.   , -15.284 , -33.286 , -58.184  ,-95.538 ,-150.   ],
       [   0. ,  0.062 ,   0.104  ,  0.112, 0.075,  0.   ,    0.     ,  0.     ,  0.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ,  0.  ,   0.  ,     0.    ,   0.    ,   0.   ,    0.     ,  0.   , -13.192 , -29.633 , -53.842  ,-92.192 ,-150.   ],
       [   0. ,  0.027 ,   0.044  ,  0.047, 0.03 ,  0.   ,    0.     ,  0.     ,  0.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ,  0.  ,   0.  ,     0.    ,   0.    ,   0.   ,    0.     ,  0.   ,  -7.851 , -18.211 , -35.36   ,-69.388 ,-150.   ],
       [   0. ,  0.    ,   0.     ,  0.   , 0.   ,  0.   ,    0.     ,  0.     ,  0.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ,  0.  ,   0.  ,     0.    ,   0.    ,   0.   ,    0.     ,  0.   ,   0.    ,   0.    ,   0.     ,  0.    ,-150.   ]]
plt.matshow(mat, aspect='auto', norm=matplotlib.colors.SymLogNorm(0.1))
plt.show()
```

which will produce the following image:

[image: that image]

---

**Explanation**:
In `matplotlib` there is option of normalization, in your case, when you handle relatively big number, and small numbers which are more important you will need to log (i.e. Logarithm) your values in order to see differences. Because you also have negative numbers simply to log them wouldn't cut it (log() doesn't handle negative obviously). As so, there is `SymLogNorm` which also handle negative numbers in the same form. 
the `0.1` is a an important parameter since the values close to zero tend toward infinity, there is a need to have a range around zero that is linear. The parameter linthresh (`0.1` as i chose here by looking to your matrix values) allows the user to specify the size of this range (-linthresh, linthresh).

for more details: [SymLogNorm documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.SymLogNorm.html#matplotlib.colors.SymLogNorm)